# XPath make output of whole XML by multiple ID's

Tags: xml, xquery, basex

```
 <bookstore>
   <book>
      <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    
    <book>
      <title lang="en" id="2">Learning XML</title>
      <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
 </bookstore>
<photostore>
 <photo>
      <title lang="en" id="3">Learning XPATH</title>
      <price>1.00</price>
    </photo>
</photostore>
```

What I trying to achieve is that XPath shows everything (including parents and anchestors) of id=1 and id=3

Output should be:

```
     <bookstore>
    <book>
      <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
 </bookstore>
<photostore>
 <photo>
      <title lang="en" id="3">Learning XPATH</title>
      <price>1.00</price>
    </photo>
</photostore>
```

Comment: Show your current XPath and current output. Also note that if you want XPath to **exclude** descendant of `bookstore` with `@id="2"` then XPath won't do that. You need to use XSLT

Comment: What is your environment? Is it a database, XQuery processor, or what?

Comment: Its just a plain xml file inside BaseX, wich is a Xquery processor. I tried //*[@id='2']/ancestor::* but it gives:'''<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <book>
    <title lang="en" id="2">Learning XML</title>
    <price>39.95</price>
  </book>
  <photostore>
    <photo>
      <title lang="en" id="3">Learning XPATH</title>
      <price>1.00</price>
    </photo>
  </photostore>
</bookstore>
<book>
  <title lang="en" id="2">Learning XML</title>
  <price>39.95</price>
</book>'''

Comment: @GJF, we are getting closer. Please fix your XML, it is not well-formed.

Comment: this xml is wellformed:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>
    <book>
      <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
      <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title lang="en" id="2">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
    <photostore>
        <photo>
             <title lang="en" id="3">Learning XPATH</title>
             <price>1.00</price>
           </photo>
       </photostore>
 </bookstore>

Comment: You can always edit your question and show code samples there in a much more readable way than throwing them in a comment. In general, if you want to select only parts of a document with other parts removed, you need more than XPath, instead you need to use XQuery or XSLT to either remove the nodes you are not interested in or construct a new document with only the nodes you are interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using BaseX 9.5.1 Beta

**XQuery**

```
declare context item := document {
<bookstore>
    <book>
        <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title lang="en" id="2">Learning XML</title>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
    <photostore>
        <photo>
            <title lang="en" id="3">Learning XPATH</title>
            <price>1.00</price>
        </photo>
    </photostore>
</bookstore>  
};

<bookstore>
{
  for $x in ./bookstore/*[descendant::*/@id=("1","3")]
  return $x
}
</bookstore>
```

**Output**

```
<bookstore>
  <book>
    <title lang="en" id="1">Harry Potter</title>
    <price>29.99</price>
  </book>
  <photostore>
    <photo>
      <title lang="en" id="3">Learning XPATH</title>
      <price>1.00</price>
    </photo>
  </photostore>
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Great thank you very much. I made it work as a command: xquery doc("./Desktop/test.xml") /bookstore/*[descendant::*/@id=("1","3")]